# How to prevent the make utility from doing the same targets simultaneously?

Tags: makefile

Let's say I have a couple of dirs, each of that contains a `makefile`. Now let's say there is a `lib` dir (with the `makefile` too) among of this dirs and there are a references to it in some of the `makefile`s in other dirs. I.e., there are some amount of the projects which depend on another one. Now, if I run the `make` utility with the `-j` option, it may to try to make the `lib` in two or more parallel threads.

Question is pretty simple: how to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have some test situation to back up your claim? If the dependencies are correct and complete (which is not trivial with many recursive makefiles) then make *does not* construct targets more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use `.NOTPARALLEL`:

```
a:
    @echo a
    @sleep 1
    @echo end a

b:
    @echo b
    @sleep 1
    @echo end b

.NOTPARALLEL:
```

Without `.NOTPARALLEL`:

```
$  gmake a b -j 2
a 
b
end a
end b
```

With `.NOTPARALLEL`:

```
$ gmake a b -j 2
a 
end a 
b 
end b
```

[GNU make's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html):

> .NOTPARALLEL
>
> If .NOTPARALLEL is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of make
>   will be run serially, even if the ‘-j’ option is given. Any
>   recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel
>   (unless its makefile also contains this target). Any prerequisites on
>   this target are ignored.

[FreeBSD's make documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)):

> .NOTPARALLEL
>     Disable parallel mode.
>
> .NO_PARALLEL
>     Synonym for .NOTPARALLEL,   for compatibility with other pmake variants.